# Using blur with text fields

Tags: jquery

I have two input text fields. One is for entering the title of the article and one is for the permalink of the article. What I'm wanting to do is have the permalink field disabled until text is inserted into the title field and when the user takes focus out of the title field then it runs a custom regex to replace spaces with hyphens and lowercases any uppercase letters.

```
<input type="text" id="title" name"title" />
<input type="text" id="permalink" name="permalink" />
```

Comment: And what have you come up with so far yourself?

Comment: Well I'm looking on the docs for jquery blur function and I'm wondering if that's what I should even be using and outside of that I'm looking to see if anyone else has used it remotely close to this and not seeing anything online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's real easy with **jQuery**...

```
var permalinkInput = $('#permalink');

$('#title').change(function() {
    permalinkInput.prop('disabled', !$(this).val());
}).change().blur(function() {
    $(this).val(function(i, value) {
        return value.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    });
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AM5Gz/).

If you don't have jQuery but only need to support **standards-compliant modern browsers**, it'd be...

```
var permalinkInput = document.querySelector('#permalink'),
    titleInput = document.querySelector('#title');

permalinkInput.disabled = true;

titleInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
    permalinkInput.disabled = !titleInput.value;
}, false);

titleInput.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    titleInput.value = titleInput.value.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RsgPb/).

If you didn't have jQuery and had to support our **old IE** friends, it'd look like...

```
var permalinkInput = document.getElementById('permalink'),
    titleInput = document.getElementById('title');

var addEvent = function(element, type, callback) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(type, callback, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent('on' + type, callback);
    } else {
        element['on' + type] = callback;
    }
}

permalinkInput.disabled = true;

addEvent(titleInput, 'change', function() {
    permalinkInput.disabled = !titleInput.value;
});

addEvent(titleInput, 'blur', function() {
    titleInput.value = titleInput.value.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uDEf2/).

Note that the old fallback for event registration is to assign the `on*` property. This will overwrite any previous property assigned there.

If you really wanted to register multiple events for these ancient browsers, you'd modify the property assignment to use a custom handler which registered and then triggered multiple events when required.

Comment: +1 for the efficiency of this code, though since permalink is used only once it doesn't need to be a variable.

Comment: @sg3s It will be however *selected* needlessly on each `change` event.

Comment: Correct. Wasn't paying attention I guess :)

Comment: For some reason the jQuery jsfiddle isn't working right for me. When the user inserts text into the title field it lowercases and replaces the spaces and puts that formatted text into the permalink field. The jsfiddle you gave ddoesn't do anything to the permalink field.

Comment: @user1333299 Your question didn't mention that. You said: *...when the user takes focus out of the title field then it runs a custom regex to replace spaces with hyphens and lowercases any uppercase letters*.

Comment: oh sorry about that misunderstanding I apologize

Comment: WHat kind of a change would be needed to adjust this?

Comment: @user1333299 Just swap the references to the `input` elements.

Comment: Didn't work either. Its supposed to put the formatted string into the permalink field and is not.

Comment: That is awesome. Amazing. Thank you very much. Definitely check mark worthy.

Comment: Well actually for some reason the field isn't staying disabled.

Comment: I think so. So would I have to apply that to the actual form element itself.

Comment: @user1333299 If you wanted it permanently disabled, just add the `disabled` attribute to your `input` element.

Comment: Do you think I would actually need this part: .change(function() {
        permalinkInput.prop('disabled', !$(this).val());

Comment: How can I add a text string in front of the text that is returned that is the same everytime.